# Java primitive datatype "short" shows 0

Tags: java, primitive-types

Please check the following..

```
short t = (short)23252525;
System.out.println(t);
```

Above will print output as "-12755"
I understand that '23252525' is too large to fit in short therefore overflows and sometimes shows negative. (– 32,768 to 32,767)

But now please take a look at this.

```
int j = 65536;
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
   System.out.println((short)(i*j));
```

Why does above always print 0s?

Thank you,

Sanone

Comment: Hint: what is `j` as a `short`?

Answer (score 5):

`65536` is `0000000000000001 0000000000000000`. Casting it to `short` leaves the bottom 16 bits, all of which are 0. When you multiply `65536` by positive integers, you get larger integers whose bottom 16 bits are still all 0.

```
0*j 00000000000000000 0000000000000000
1*j 00000000000000001 0000000000000000
2*j 00000000000000010 0000000000000000
3*j 00000000000000011 0000000000000000
4*j 00000000000000100 0000000000000000
5*j 00000000000000101 0000000000000000
6*j 00000000000000110 0000000000000000
7*j 00000000000000111 0000000000000000
8*j 00000000000001000 0000000000000000
9*j 00000000000001001 0000000000000000
```

Therefore i*j remains 0 when cast to short.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's multiple of 65536 which overflows to 0.

So as pointed out by you, the range of short is –32,768 to 32,767,

```
so when you have short as 32768, it overflows and goes to –32768, 
if your short goes to 32769, it will print -32767.
```

Similarly if your short goes to 65536, it goes back to 0 and hence you see 0.